# Setting color that depends on the background

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to SCSS. I have the following code:

```
.answers-post {
  float: left;

  .btn {
    background: white;

    &:hover {
      background: dark-light-diff($primary, $secondary, 65%, -75%);
      color: $secondary;
    }
  }
}
```

It sets the background of the button to be white. Some of the users which use our scripts, have a white background. So a small idea came to my head - Is it possible somehow to check the color of the background and if it a **kind of** white, than it will not set it white (will not set any color). By kind of, I mean that the hex value is between two points of white (not sure which).

I'm sorry in advance if this questions sound odd, I'm not quite sure if its a reasonable idea in scss but from reading the docs, scss is a powerful tool that contains alot of interesting ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to check the luminance of the RGB values:

```
var c = '#F48024'.substring(1);      // strip #
var rgb = parseInt(c, 16);   // convert rrggbb to decimal
var r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;  // extract red
var g = (rgb >>  8) & 0xff;  // extract green
var b = (rgb >>  0) & 0xff;  // extract blue

var luma = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b; // per ITU-R BT.709

if (luma > 90) {
    // pick not white
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to achieve without JS?

Comment: No, the most you can do is detect if the person is using light or dark mode on their phone: https://css-tricks.com/dark-modes-with-css/